# How to do cyclic momentum just like cyclic learning rate?

Tags: tensorflow

I want the momentum to cycle from 0.95 to 0.85. I have seen some Keras implementation where you can K.set(model.opt.momentum, value) in the callback. However, in TensorFlow there is no momentum attribute in SGD optimizer. I'm using TensorFlow 2.2

Will this code below work? How can I know if it work?

```
class momsec(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):


    def __init__(self, initial_mom,maximal_mom,step_size):
        super().__init__()

        self.initial_mom = initial_mom
        self.maximal_mom = maximal_mom
        self.step_size=step_size
        self.step=0


    def __call__(self):
        with tf.name_scope("CyclicalMom"):


            initial_mom = tf.convert_to_tensor(
            self.initial_mom, name="initial_mom")
            dtype = initial_mom.dtype
            maximal_mom = tf.cast(self.maximal_mom, dtype)
            step_size = tf.cast(self.step_size, dtype)
            cycle = tf.floor(1 + self.step / (2 * step_size))

            x = tf.abs(self.step / step_size - 2 * cycle + 1)

            mom=initial_mom + (
                    maximal_mom - initial_mom
                ) * tf.maximum(tf.cast(0, dtype), (1 - x)) 
            self.step+=1
            return mom

    def get_config(self):
        return {
            "initial_mom": self.initial_mom,
            "maximal_mom": self.maximal_mom,
            "step_size": self.step_size,

        }    
mom=momsec(0.95,0.85,600)
opt = tensorflow.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=lr,momentum=mom,nesterov=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using Variable

```
import tensorflow as tf
mom = tf.Variable(0.2)
opt = tf.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.001, momentum=mom)
mom.assign(0.999)
print(opt.get_config())
```